# Is there any way to trick the compiler into allowing this?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xaml

I have a XAML workflow equivalent to

```
Bar bar;

if (foo.SomeFlag)
{
    // ... do stuff

    bar = .. // set bar, guaranteed unless exception thrown earlier in this block
}

// do other stuff 

// here it is guaranteed that foo.SomeFlag is the same as it was before
if (foo.SomeFlag)
{
   // use bar
}
```

in plain C#, how I'm trying to rewrite it. The problem is that I'm getting `Use of unassigned variable 'bar' ..` compiler error. I understand the error, but I thought I might be able to overcome it by writing

```
Bar bar;

const bool someFlag = foo.SomeFlag;

if (someFlag)
{
    // ... do stuff

    bar = .. // set bar, guaranteed unless exception thrown earlier in this block
}

// do other stuff 

if (someFlag)
{
   // use bar
}
```

but apparently that isn't valid syntax.

Any ideas how to overcome?

Comment: Why don't you set `bar` to `null` and check for that later on? Your flags may become out-of-sync over time.

Comment: You can use an `else` block, but it's unclear what you're trying to do

Comment: There *is* actually a known definite assignment bug that *could* be used to trick this, but your code would be instantly buggy. Don't try and trick the compiler: just ... assign it a value!

Comment: Refactor your `// Do Other Stuff` out and don't split the condition: `if (!someFlag) DoOtherStuff(); else { DoStuff(); bar = SetBar() ;DoOtherStuff(); UseBar(bar); }`

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is requiring that `bar` is set to some value before you use it, and since `someFlag` could potentially change between your `if` blocks (meaning that the first block may not run but the second block could), it will give you an error. To avoid this, you can just set bar to a default value initially:

```
Bar bar = default(Bar);   // this will be 'null' for class objects
```

Then the rest of your code should work as expected

```
const bool someFlag = foo.SomeFlag;

if (someFlag)
{
    // Do something, assign bar to new value
    bar = new Bar();
}

// Do some other stuff 

// Possibly add a check that bar was set, just to be safe...
if (someFlag && bar != null)
{
    // Use bar
    bar.DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tricking the compiler to allow it will imply that your solution will have a chance for an exception.

Think, what happens if foo.SomeFlag is not true? The value for bar will be null or to be more specific it will be default(Bar). (Yes, the compiler knows what is the default value for any type). If, like I think you intend, Bar is a class then the value will be null for sure. Then when it tries to use bar, lets say you try bar.Something it will throw an exception. The compiler is actually protecting you against it.

The solution is just a null check before using bar. Like:

```
if (someFlag)
{
   if(bar != null)
   {
       // use bar
   }
}
```

Nonetheless, I strongly suggest to start initializing your variables so you know for sure and wont forget. Like:

Solution 1: Start bar with something.

```
Bar bar = null; // <- Only if you know for sure Bar is a class
// or
Bar bar = default(Bar);

if (foo.SomeFlag)
{
    ...
}
```

Solution 2: Make an else

```
if (foo.SomeFlag)
{
   ...
}
else
{
    bar = null; // <- Only if you know for sure Bar is a class
    // or
    bar = default(bar);
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler isn't smart enough to recognize if your `if` block will actually be executed. Therefore it assumes that `bar` could possibly not be initialized before it's used. To mitigate this, just give `bar` an initial value by setting it to `null` or provide an `else` statement.

```
Bar bar = null;

const bool someFlag = foo.SomeFlag;

if (someFlag)
{
    // ... do stuff

    bar = .. // set bar, guaranteed unless exception thrown earlier in this block
}

// do other stuff 

if (someFlag)
{
   // use bar
}
```

Or:

```
Bar bar;

const bool someFlag = foo.SomeFlag;

if (someFlag)
{
    // ... do stuff

    bar = .. // set bar, guaranteed unless exception thrown earlier in this block
}
else
{
    bar = null;
}

// do other stuff 

if (someFlag)
{
   // use bar
}
```